# How to return object with its ManyToManyField related object

Tags: django, rest, orm

I have a model, for example, A has a field xxx (ManyToManyField with B model). How can I query and return like:

```
{
   'f1': 'xxx',
   'f2': 'yyy',
    photos: [{photo1}, {photo2},...]
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm django newbie :D

Comment: Can you give a (fake, if you like) [simple complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the models code? Just enough to let us run the code and see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
B.objects.get(pk=1).a.all().values()
```

You can try this and get all the columns,  if you need specific you can pass them inside values.

Remember a is the model A or the model you want to use in all small letter

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these models:

```python
from django.db import models

class LoremIpsum(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField()
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo')

class Photo(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField()
```

Because the `LoremIpsum.photos` field is a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), its value will act as a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/):

```python
lorem_ipsum = LoremIpsum.objects.get(identifier="dolor")
photo_filenames = [photo.filename for photo in lorem_ipsum.photos.all()]
```